# A way to set win32 window scrollbar to the left?

Tags: windows, winapi, scrollbar

Is there a way in Win32 API to set the place of vertical scrollbar to the left border of the window(a native one maybe).

I've looked at the WS definition and there is only WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR but its for right to left text.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR doesn't work?  The documentation says it should "[place] a vertical scroll bar to the left of the client area."

Comment: Yes i found that i only works for arab text if the text is not arab then it ignores it.

Comment: You will have to create a standalone scroll bar.

Comment: I was thinking about that but is a bit of a pain for a simple scrollbar. Well i guess i have no choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  It seems that the documentation varies depending on where you look.  If you look under "Extended Window Styles", it says:

> WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR   Places a vertical scroll bar to the left of the client area.

But if you look under CreateWindowEx, it says:

> WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR
>   If the shell language is Hebrew, Arabic, or another language that supports reading order alignment, the vertical scroll bar (if present) is to the left of the client area. For other languages, the style is ignored.

So I have no idea what the official answer is.  I did try it on my machine (Windows 7 Professional) and the scrollbar appeared on the left.

```
CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR,
                (LPCTSTR)classAtom,
                _T( "Test Window" ),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                hInstance,
                NULL );
```

Comment: Well,i gave up searching for an official way to do this and just made a custom one.